# Download files from git remote repository

Tags: git

So this is the thing: I've got a process that should download files from git remote repository and deploy them onto destination server which does not have a git installed on.

In addition, I should be able to download the files based on a given git tag and only the HEAD.

What is the best way to  such thing?

Answer (score 3):

In order to achieve one easy copy between the git remote repo content and your destination, you can consider using **[`git archive`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-archive.html)**.
See "[Git Tip of the Week: Git Archive](http://alblue.bandlem.com/2011/09/git-tip-of-week-git-archive.html)"

> One key advantage of using Git to perform the archive rather than a command line tool is to avoid accidentally capturing the (large) .git directory, or any work-in-progress content. For example, if you have just run a build, then zip (tar) will include the content of the build output as well.
>
> Another advantage is that you can extract the content of the repository at **an arbitrary revision**.

Plus, copying one file aver the network is less error-prone than rsync'ing a large set of files.